# In the ring of even integers , do 4 and 6 have a lcm and gcd? If they have , what are they?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a solution, but I have a doubt in it.

regarding gcd :
2 is not gcd for 4 and 6 because 2 does not divides 6 , as it gives 3 which does not belongs to set of even integers ring.

regarding lcm : (i have doubt)
the solutions shows 12 is not lcm because 4|12 (= 3) which does not belongs to set of even integers ring but then why not 24 is a solution to lcm of 4 and 6 in a set of even integers??

Comment: I suggest you look up your definition of a divisor. (The number you get after dividing, need not be in the ring, but can be any integer, or element of the ring). You may also want to think about this in terms of ideals (a, b) = (g) where g is gcd(a,b). Can you think about lcm? Prove any claims you use but have not proved already

Comment: @mdave16 In what definition of "divisor" would the number you get after dividing not need to be in the ring? With this logic, we would have that $5$ divides $3$, as $5/3 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Well, yes, it is not in the ring (which is $\mathbb{Z}$ in this example), but...

Comment: Are notions of divisibility well-behaved if you're going to talk about nonunital rings? How are you defining the terms?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold, I use the definition that after division, it's either in the ring or an integer. (Since the ideal generated by $a$ would be $\{ra + as + na : r, s \in R \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. To the point you raised, I think any unit is a divisor of $3$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, since $3/u$ will still be in $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I think I might be in need of looking up definitions as this is obviously not what egreg's answer suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $E$ be the (nonunital) ring of even integers. A common divisor of $4$ and $6$ in $E$ is also a common divisor in the integers, so the only candidate is $2$; however, as you observe, this is not a divisor of $6$ in $E$. Therefore the two elements have *no* common divisor.

Similarly, a common multiple in $E$ is also a common multiple in the integers, so we have to look to numbers of the form $12x$; since $12x/4=3x$, we need $x$ to be even. The candidate for the lcm is thus $24$. Is it?

Note that “least common multiple” means “a common multiple that divides every other common multiple” (the standard order relation in the integers is not considered).

Now try $72$.

Can any other common multiple be the lowest common multiple?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, that's another example (but is essentially the same, because $-24=72-24\cdot 4$).